# Android - How to get the device used memory and storage?

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

As the title says, I am trying to get my device used memory and storage by using this cordova plugin:
cordova-plugin-extended-device-information.
However, it seems to get the the state once at deviceReady and doesn't update later for example: on deviceready it says:

---

- freestorage:5803
- memory:"1512.3"
- totalstorage:"5951"

---

And those values are never updated. Since i need to know those real values when the user requests, for example, when the user loaded the database of my application, it does not provide me with usefull information.
Am I doing something wrong or this is the way it was supposed to work?
Also, if there is another way to get these, I am open to suggestions.

Note: I use Ionic 1, angularJS, cordova on this project. May or may not be related, i have the plugin cordova-plugin-device installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [cordova-plugin-extended-device-information](https://github.com/danielehrhardt/cordova-plugin-extended-device-information) which gets the required device information for android.

It has methods to get the following

- device.memory
- device.cpumhz
- device.totalstorage
- device.freestorage

EDIT

For updated states, maybe you could try [this](https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/cordova-plugin-chrome-apps-system-memory)

Comment: As I have pointed on my question, i am using this exactly plugin, but either I am using it wrong, since the values returned never changes, or I am missing something.
I am testing using this line on my debbuger:
cordova.plugins['extended-device-information']
before and after loading the database, but the values does not change

Comment: oh sorry, misread device plugin for device extended. What is the plugin version you are using?

Comment: The version is 2.2.0. The latest, if I am not mistaken

Comment: That gave me the total storage and the free storage. I have yet to find a way to get the memory used. But I guess it is helpful enought, one less problem to deal with. Once again, thanks.